# Using JInput instead of $_POST

Tags: joomla-3.4, jinput, array

By using `var_dump($_POST);`, I'm getting the following output:

```
array(2) 
{
    ["data"] => array(2) 
    {
        ["title"] => "XXX"
        ["server"] => "XXXXXX"
    }
    ["Itemid"] => "101"
}
```

My aim is to get the `server` value. I can easily achieve this by using:

```
$_POST['data']['server'];
```

Having snooped around, I found that using the following **can** be used:

```
$array  = $input->post->getArray(array());      
$server = $array['data']['server'];
```

Is this the best approach for `JInput` or is there something better?

Comment: Docs are pretty vague on arrays, but perhaps https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/cf0f84abe8f706085ea7e836c53fbf7af9673d94/libraries/joomla/input/input.php may help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$values = $app->input->getArray(array('data'=>'array'));
echo $values['data']['server'];
```

Please see I did not mention post variable specifically, because this can retrieve both get and post values. If you need to get a value from a specific super global, such as post, you can use something like `$app->input->post`

You can retrieve multiple values by passing their names and data type in above format. This way you can get exactly what you want instead of getting raw data which is potentially not safe. Always mention the data type that you require.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
$data = $input->post->get('data', array(), 'ARRAY');
$server = $data['server'];
```

Haven't a playground to test this in, but I think it works.

Comment: Isn't this method used in an older version of the platform?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the method is in the current source, since 11.1, with no deprecated notice.